# In SQL SSRS I would like to switch column 1 to column2

Tags: reporting-services

In SQL 2016 SSRS I would like to switch column 1 to column2 while I am working on it.

How can i do that?

Thanks,

Comment: When you run the report (not possible) or when authoring?

Comment: Simply turn the report upside down

Answer (score 1):

Just delete one of the column from your table, insert a new column to the left or right of the left column, put in the data again.

COMPLETE!

Answer (score 1):

If the column is done, and you are just looking to change the order, the easiest way to switch it without deleting the column and remaking it is to change the order of it in the xml code.

Open your report, go to View -> code. Hit Ctrl+F and enter in your column name, copy relevant code, and re-position as need be.